# Spring boot 3 - springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui not working with openapi-generator-maven-plugin api generator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I'm using spring boot 3, & i'm trying to generate openapi documentation in /swagger/index.html.
I found out that it's enough to add the following dependency alone :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Since I am using an api generator using the plugin (openapi-generator-maven-plugin), the app crashes on startup with the following exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration':
 Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setFilterChains' parameter 0:
 Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [ma/d7k/api/app/configuration/SecurityConfig.class]:
 Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain]:
 Factory method 'filterChain' threw exception with message:
 Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
 Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]:
 Failed to introspect Class [org.springdoc.webmvc.api.OpenApiWebMvcResource] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@1d44bcfa]
```

---

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
private final JwtProvider jwtProvider;

public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService, JwtProvider jwtProvider) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    this.jwtProvider = jwtProvider;
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilterBefore(new JwtFilter(jwtProvider, userDetailsService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.cors().and()
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .httpBasic(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                    .requestMatchers(EndpointsConstants.GENERAL_ALLOWED_ENDPOINTS).permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers(EndpointsConstants.USER_ALLOWED_ENDPOINTS).permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated());
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Can you share SecurityConfig ?

Comment: yes here is the edit